# jQuery UI Tooltip with Arrow, why/how does this code work?

Tags: css, jquery-ui, tooltip

I'm trying to wrap my head around the following example
http://jsfiddle.net/marlonpp/HkTE9/1/

This is the CSS the example uses

```
  body { padding: 20px; }

/*input[type="button"] { margin: 100px 0 0 10px; }*/
input[type="button"] { margin: 10px 0 0 10px; }

.ui-tooltip {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    position: absolute;
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid #767676;
    max-width: 180px;
    z-index: 9999;

}

.ui-tooltip-content::after, .ui-tooltip-content::before {
    top: 100%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
}

.bottom .ui-tooltip-content::after {
    border-color: rgba(118, 118, 118, 0);
    border-top-color: white;
    border-width: 10px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -10px;
}

.bottom .ui-tooltip-content::before {
    border-color: rgba(118, 118, 118, 0);
    border-top-color: #767676;
    border-width: 11px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -11px;
}

.top .ui-tooltip-content::after {
    top: -10px;
    left: 50%;
    border-color: white transparent;
    border-width: 0 10px 10px;
    margin-left: -10px;
}

.top .ui-tooltip-content::before {
     border-color: rgba(118, 118, 118, 0);
     border-bottom-color: #767676;
     top: -11px;
     left: 50%;
     border-width: 0 11px 11px;
     margin-left: -11px;
 }
```

It creates a nice triangle arrow for the tooltip and it does it with borders.
The one thing I really don't understand:

Why or how does it work?
I don't understand why it seems to be transformed 45 degrees without any transformation rule?

I tried to take this example and create an arrow for the left and the right side but since I don't how it works in the first place I fail.

Any ideas/explanations?

Comment: [css tricks triangle](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/) my this helps you to understand

Comment: like somebody in the comments (in your link) said, this is trippy ;)
If you add it as answer I will mark it as solution. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a good explanation is at:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

or

http://davidwalsh.name/css-triangles

I think they say all you need to know about css triangles